How to save original file name when using Save As
We use a template Excel file for our employees. In it, I would like to document the file name that was used within a cell in the main worksheet. Of note, they cannot save data in the template, and when they hit Save, it opens the Save As dialogue box. I am looking for a way to store the original file name in the file they create to know which version of the template they used (we release new versions).
Is there a VBA code (or any other solution) for this?

I would create a defined named in the workbook .... you can always refer to that (caveat is it could be deleted by a savvy user who wanted to do so (I think it is even possible to create hidden defined names for even more obscurity).

Example here: https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/use-named-constants-to-store-numbers/ (in this case the name is SalesTax and the value is .065 but in your case the name could be "TemplateName" and the value can be "MyTemplateName" - or TemplateVersion and so on)

You can also put something in the file properties as well - under File | Info there are editable property values for a workbook.

A hidden Shape or Comment is another possible option.

For those that are unable to utilize the templates, you can use ActiveWorkbook.name to capture the name, and within a Workbook_BeforeSave or Workbook_Open event, you can prompt and direct as such (but would require people enable macros... you can save however you want prior to enabling macros).  VBA safeguards are akin to a screendoor on a submarine... sometimes you need to find other protections to even get that far, e.g., workbook locked by default, but once macros are enabled it turns off the protections as part of the _Open event and then triggers the Workbook.SaveAs.

If you're updating the template why not update a global Const in the template's vbproject with the new name at the same time? No need for every user to run code to capture that.

@topsail There's also the Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties option too, which is less immediately user-visible, and will persist even if the file is saved as XLSX

Thank you all for your ideas.
Since I update the template to a new version routinely, I was looking to have something that can update the parameter/constant/whatever solution I use, such that the new template filename is saved in the file.
I already have a locked cell in which I manually save the new template filename, but was looking to automate it.
BTW, I call it a template file, but in reality it is a password protected file that the users need to open in Read-Only mode and then save a copy with Save As.
